# Difficulty in plugging in multiple variables into an equation

Tags: replacement

[image]

When I try to plugging in the the value of e_{1} and e_{2} into the following equation, it shows me error.
Is there any other options?

Comment: What do you consider as the unknowns and should be solved? BTW, please post also copiable codes rather than just a screenshot.

Comment: I tried to add the code but it does not allow me to post. My unknown is SWF as an equation and I want to plug in the value of e_{1} and e_{2} on that equation. This is my second day on using mathematica

Comment: Jui, you can edit your question by clicking the pencil icon. When you do this, it will be better for us to know what is SWF defined as, also, so that the ability for us to help you answer this question is improved.